# How to find $f(x)$ in a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[pollution concentration C(x) in a sand layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkeON.png)

Please have a look at the following image^

I need to be able to find $f(x)$ in order to move forward with this solution.

$-DAC''(x)+vAC'(x)=f(x)$

I know that from the given conditions $f(x)$ is some piecewise function:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, &0<x<200 \\
p(x), &200<x<1800 \\
0, &1800<x<2000
\end{cases}
$$

I just have no idea how I would solve for $p(x)$??

PLEASE help!!! Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are D,A,v given constants? what do you know about C(x)

Comment: D= 10^8
A=10
C(0)=0
C(200)=120
C(1800)=70
C(2000)=0
Take v=1

Comment: Seems you are missing some information. Where did this problem come from?